# Sorting keys and cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary

I'm new to iOS programming. I have to sort my keys in my NSDictionary or more like reverse the order of my keys.

What my current keys right now are like this;

Oh! And I do not have values for my keys as they are taken out from my XML.

NSDictionary (called GradDict);

```
2012 S1
2012 S2
```

I want it to be like this;

```
2012 S2
2012 S1
```

Here are my codes to sort it;

In parserDidEndDocument:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [gradDict keyEnumerator];
id key;

while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    NSLog(@"Key:%@",key);
    NSLog(@"%@", [gradDict objectForKey:key]);

}
self.sort = [key sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
ModuleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ModuleCell"];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ModuleCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSString *period = [self.sort objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSMutableArray *periodArray = [gradDict objectForKey:period];
Module *m = [periodArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.moduleNameLabel setText:[m moduleName]];
[cell.moduleCreditLabel setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", [m moduleCredits]]];
[cell.moduleGradeLabel setText:[m moduleGrade]];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.75 green:0.93 blue:1 alpha:1];
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.55 green:0.55 blue:0.55 alpha:1]];

return cell;
```

Am I doing the sorting wrongly?
And how am I to do the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to sort the data in the dictionary, right?
But the dictionary sorting is not saved. You can sort the keys and then create an array.

Comment: I created a property for the sort array for sorted keys. It should be saved, right? But I'm not sure if my codes work correctly or if my keys are already sorted. @Dmitry